# Google Maps iOS SDK Linking error "Undefined symbols for architecture arm64"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps

Please help I want to use Google Maps SDK
in the existing old project. I can't use Pods here.
I tried to add Google Maps SDK by manually

I follow the instruction from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start

it's error when linking binary.

### [image: Google Maps Framework iOS]

### [image: Framework Search Path Google Maps iOS]

[image: Undefined symbols for architecture arm64]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing **9th Point** of Google Map manual Implementation

i.e ( Choose your project, rather than a specific target, and open the Build Settings tab. In the Other Linker Flags section, add -ObjC. If these settings are not visible, change the filter in the Build Settings bar from Basic to All. )

(Manual Intergration google map link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start)